# how to make a general purpose report

Tags: c#, sql-server, report

1. I have a form it's purpose to view a (photo and name and bio) in a
   db called info, and every person has a number of activity in a db
   called Activity.

   I need when the user view a person in the form the
   user can press a button called report Activity for this person.

   I know the query `"Select * from Activity where id = '"+ Txtid.Text 
   +"'"` but I can't do it, it only require a pure sql command without Txtid.Text So how to include the `Txtid.text` within the query?
2. How can I send any query and the result will come out in a report?

> Note: I am using ado to connect to the db I use sql server db.

I need the simplest way to do it (away from crystal report) if possible.

Comment: @Ezzat..There are many ways to pass a parameter in sql. You can store the value of your textbox in a string (or) object (or) datatable. Please specify your reuirement..

Comment: well, it seems parameter is what i look for, but i dont know how to do it, and does report accept parameter to show data?, i honstly cant tell.

Comment: Fine, do you need to perform the operation on a button click or a text change event.. Could you brief on the occurance of 'Txtid.Text'.

Comment: Would you prefer a string instead of 'Txtid.Text'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find it on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nQvWNAldA1E
it was very simple